# Problema a la hora de registrar un producto

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

El problema que tengo es que cuando registro, en este caso un producto, me registra normal pero el problema es que lo registra 2 veces, me registra todo bien en la Base de datos pero lo que pasa es que lo manda 2 veces y obviamente aparecerá error en la PRIMARY KEY porque está siendo mandada 2 veces.

Este es el error de PK duplicada:

```
"Duplicate entry 'P0001' for key 'PRIMARY'"
```

Aquí mi servlet:

```
 /**
 * Servlet implementation class RegistroProductoServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/rp")
public class RegistroProductoServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public RegistroProductoServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
procesar(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    procesar(request, response);

}

private void procesar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String codprod = request.getParameter("txtCodigo");
    String fecharegistro = request.getParameter("txtFecha");
    String descripcion = request.getParameter("txtDescripcion");
    double precio = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txtPrecio"));
    int tipo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cboTipo"));
    int stock = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtStock"));


    ProductoService ser = new ProductoService();

    ProductoDTO p = new ProductoDTO(codprod, fecharegistro, descripcion, tipo, stock, precio);
    int ok = ser.registrarProducto(p);

    if(ok!=0){
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>Registro de Productos</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Producto Registrado!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>");   
            out.println("</body></html>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error aqui en el servlet de registro producto");
        }finally{
            out.close();
        }
    }else{
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/registroproducto.jsp");
        try {
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: No será que estás haciendo "doble click" sobre el botón o link que dispara el request? Lo que te aconsejo es que mires el log de tu servidor web para comprobarlo.

Comment: No es un buen idea de escribir HTML en Java. (yo sabe que no es el problem).

Comment: Por favor publica el código completo de tu servlet e incluye el mapping de urls que tenga definido en la anotación `@WebServlet` o vía web.xml

Comment: En el @WebServlet le puse esto: 

        @WebServlet("/rp")

Y ese nombre rp, lo estoy poniendo en el action del formulario del registro.

        <form action="rp" method="post">
           /*contenido del formulario*/
       </form>

 Imagen del servlet completo(lo que falta, ya q complementa con la del post).

          [https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=error.jpg]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y publica todo lo necesario para replicar el problema en la pregunta. No dependas de sitios externos para proveer información sobre el problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Lo siento, ahí está.

Comment: La parte:

      @WebServlet("/rp"): rp tambien esta en el form

<form action="rp">
   /*contenido del formulario*/

</form>

Comment: Muchas gracias, @LuiggiMendoza.

Exactamente ese era el problema, mil gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que el método `procesar` se está llamando dos veces. Aquí:

```
protected void doGet(/* ... */) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //...
    procesar(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(/* ... */) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //doGet llama a procesar
    doGet(request, response);
    //luego vuelves a llamar a procesar y se produce el error
    procesar(request, response);
}
```

Solución: no llames al método `doGet` en el método `doPost`.

Algo aún más importante es que los métodos `doGet` y `doPost` **no deben hacer lo mismo**. Este es un grave problema que aparece normalmente cuando trabajas con NetBeans. Te recomiendo que no utilices el método `procesar` en ambos métodos puesto que cada uno tiene una responsabilidad diferente:

- [GET](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3): Método para obtener información del servidor. Usualmente obtiene los datos de query string. No debe modificar información que ya existe en el servidor. Usualmente se usa para navegar entre los elementos de una aplicación Web y sus recursos.
- [POST](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5): Método para procesar la información de los datos enviados. Los datos usualmente están en el cuerpo del mensaje. Este método puede (dependiendo del caso) agregar, actualizar o eliminar información.